# Create-React-App Optimization used on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, gzip

I am looking for help in optimizing a React App for Heroku.

1. I have bought a translating XD Design to React on Fiverr.
2. The Translator used SCSS and Bootstrap to create all the Frontend.
3. I then added a little bit of web3js on top of it and restyled some components for my likings.
4. Deployed my app to Heroku.

Everything works great but the problem is that the application has a very long load time (low performance). Google Page Speed Insight shows over 16s of load time, which is huge. The main reason is lack of text compression. Now, I have installed some compression methods and when building the app I have all the "br" and "gz" files but I think it is not being loaded on Heroku, as load times did not change. I also did state in the server.js to use those files (following some tutorial) but it did not affect anything. Can anyone point me to some resource on how to optimize it?

```
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression');
const favicon = require('express-favicon');
const path = require('path');
const expressStaticGzip = require('express-static-gzip');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/build/favicon.ico'));
// the __dirname is the current directory from where the script is running
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(compression());
app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
 return res.send('pong');
});
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build');
app.use(
  '/',
  expressStaticGzip(buildPath, {
    enableBrotli: true,
    orderPreference: ['br', 'gz']
  })
);

// Fallback to index.html when something that doesn't exist is requested
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'), err => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
  });
});
app.listen(port);
```